# Datetime format for converting a string data into UTC based datetime

Tags: python, datetime, type-conversion

I have this date data:

```
timestamp="2016-11-01T18:18:46.5035795Z"
```

I am looking for a correct **dtfmt** so I can convert the data above to a proper datatime value with **UTC** set as timezone (tzinfo)

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, dtfmt)
```

Can anybody help ? Thanks

Comment: That looks like an ISO-8601 format (just providing an idea for googling it) You might also want to take a look to https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module is ideal for this

```
pip install python_dateutil
```

and then

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse(timestamp)
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 18, 18, 46, 503579, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Without the dateutil module you have to use regex to strip out the extra character in the microseconds part of the string, and then use the right date format that matches the string to convert it to a `datetime` object

```
>>> import re
>>> timestamp = re.findall('.*[0-9]{6}', timestamp)[0] + 'Z'
>>> datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 18, 18, 46, 503579)
```

Comment: Thanks danidee!
One more question, when I do the pareser part the result i get is this:
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 18, 18, 46, 503579, tzinfo=tzlocal())

how can I force it to tzutc() ?